# How to make a protected file list on my server?

Tags: protected, .htpasswd

I've a silly question. I did not create a protected list of folder and file on my server with htaccess.

I've a folder protect with htpasswd. There is this in my htaccess :

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "My Protected Area"
AuthUserFile .htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

But when i add this line for list the folder, i've an 500 error :

```
Options +Indexes
```

i've you got an idea of the problem ?

Sorry for my bad english !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must specify an absolute path for the `.htpasswd` file. Try using an absolute path from the `/` folder from your machine.

Example:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "My Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /var/yourpath/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

**TIP:** I created a Gist on Github to help developers creating a basic `.htaccess` file. You can [find it here](https://gist.github.com/fiftydegrees/b8c56422ca3b85c49978).